# How to filter JSON inside an angular ionic component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to map and filter a JSON inside a component but I have not succeeded, from the service "data.services.ts" I had no problem, but when taking the data to the component "tab1.page.ts" I couldn't, the usual thing I do is use:

```
.pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
        return res
    })
);
```

**Tab1.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.services';

import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { filter } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  items = []

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data=> {
        this.items = data
      })
  }

}
```

**data.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { filter } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getRemoteData() {
        return this.http
        .get("https://api")
        .pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                return res.prosugApi
            })
        );
    }
}
```

**I'm trying:**

```
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  items = []

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data=> {
        this.items = data
        return this.items.filter((filter1) => {
          return filter1.sublinea == "SOFA"
        })
        });       
      }
  }
```

But I have not been lucky.

Comment: can you show console.log result from `this.items` or `data`?

Comment: and i think you dont need the inside return. `return this.items.filter(fitler1 => filter1.sublinea == "SOFA")` will be enough

Comment: Can you make a console log. 
 map((res: any) => {
                 console log(res)
                return res.prosugApi
            })